# Cannot install es_core_news_sm from Spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

When I try to install es_core_news_sm
with this commmand

```
python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm
```

with conda I get this error

```
No module name spacy._main_;'spacy'is a package and cannot be directly executed.
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen if conda installed an older version of spaCy. See the following [issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2462) on spaCy's github.

The fix as stated in the issue is as follows:

1. Find the most recent version of spaCy on conda:`conda search -f spacy`
2. Then run: `conda install spacy=NEWEST_VERSION`

The newest version of spaCy on [Conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spacy) is 2.0.18

Comment: My spaCy version is 2.0.16. But when I try to install the newest version I have this error : The following packages are not available from the current version.

Comment: Trying to update to the newest version, it says that the 2.0.18 is installed but I cannot install the es_core_news_sm

Comment: I think you have multiple versions of spaCy installed which might be culprit. I am not a conda user, I use pip and use virtual-environments to keep my installations of different versions clean. Do not know how it works in conda.

Can you please share your stack trace?